# 5 year-old daughter has difficulty identifying colours

Tags: pre-schooler

My daughter is now 5 years old and she can't identify any colour.

When I teach a colour to her and, after few minutes, ask her what this colour is, she fails to repeat that colour.

What can I do to help, or at least understand the problem?

Comment: Does she remember the name of the color (is it a "verbal" or a "visual" problem)? Did you already see a doctor to check her eyes?

Comment: To clarify the above comment: does she say color words, but misapply them? Or does she fail to remember the words altogether?

Comment: Are you sure she is not color blind?  Have you had her tested?

Comment: My brother is color blind. He said in school he would just say any color when the teacher asked him. It was about 1st grade when he was tested.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure she is not color blind? Have you had her tested?

Have you been around someone that is color bind?  You can point to something that is red and tell them it is red and they know how to match that shade of gray (e.g. find another red sock).  Buy you cannot shut the drawer and open it and ask them to pick out two red socks (unless they still have the first red sock).

Comment: Colour-blindness tests [are available online](http://www.colour-blindness.com/colour-blindness-tests/ishihara-colour-test-plates/) for a quick self-assessment -- which should always be backed up by a professional opinion if it indicates that there may be a problem, or that there is definitely no colour-blindness issue but individual colours cannot be accurately identified.